# Python: max & min functions

Tags: python, max, min

I really don't understand the max or min functions, the meaning of them. For instance, when i write these in the notepad++, in the output i see a letter of the word. And i can't understand it. Why only this letter, not another letters of this word? 
Please, help me on this way. Thanks

**In the Notepad++**

- x = max ("Hello Home")
- print x
- y = min ("World")
- print y

**In the Output**

- o
- W

[image: Input&Output image]

Comment: Did you read the documentation on [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)?

Comment: Look [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the answer.

Comment: It's all in the _ASCII values_.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Letters have a numerical value assigned to them and `min` or `max` will find the minimum or maximum of those numerical values.

Comment: What were you expecting instead?! Why apply those functions to strings at all?

Comment: `o` and `W` have a relatively high value because they come later in the alphabet.

Comment: Thanks for help,everyone. I understand the meaning of these functions. I have never heard about the ASCII values. I am beginner on this field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the ASCII table

- Capital letters points to decimal 65 to 90 (65-90 → A-Z )
- Small letters points to decimal 97-122 (97-122 → a-z)

so, max value = o (decimal 111)
min value = W (decimal 87)

#### ASCII table  for your reference

[image: ASCII table]

Comment: I don't hear about ASCII table. But now i understand my question's answer. Thank you very much for information.

Answer (score 3):

To find out why, you can `map` `ord` over the strings:

```
>>> list(map(ord, "Hello Home"))
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 72, 111, 109, 101]
```

The highest number in there is 111, which corresponds to "o" (the ASCII value of "o" is 111).

Comment: I understand the meaning of them. But now i have another question for you. 
Although they have same values, is it first "o" or second "o" ?

Comment: It really makes no difference in this case, but technically it should be the first "o".